# Laravel eloquent relationships, Models, and getting them in one try

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Finally when I thought I've got the hang of Laravel Eloquent Relationships and how to work with them, I am again stuck on the same issue I started with a couple of days ago.

i-e Getting Relationships resolved and assigning / unassigning for 1-N,N-N relationships.

My question is really simple and straight forward. Teach me the ways of this eloquent Zen once and for all.

I have a Model class "Vehicle.php" and a Model class "User.php"

```
User hasMany Vehicle
Vehicle belongsTo User
```

Here is how I retrieve my "vehicle".

```
$vehicle = $this->user->vehicles()->where('id',$params['vehicle_id'])->first()
```

And here is how I am trying to get my associated User.

```
return $vehicle->user()->first(); //return $vehicle->user
```

And I keep getting

```
Call to a member function first() on null
```

Help me clear my understanding of this part of laravel. I have gone through many threads / tutorials but I keep falling into the same ditch again.

**Vehicle.php**

```
public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

**User.php**

```
public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Vehicle');
    }
```

Comment: a vehicle belongs to only user right? then why are you using first(), the query should return only one record

Comment: Do you have a user associated with the vehicle in your database? because that is what the error is saying. Also for a belongsTo relationship you can just do : `$vehicle->user` , no need for the brackets and first. The docs are pretty clear too : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: as can be seen in the commented part of the code, i tried $vehicle->user . nothing seems to work. Yes 'vehicles' table does have a 'user_id' column and it is filled properly. And Yes the docs are clear on how it should be , but I must be misunderstanding something . hence I keep falling for the same thing.

Comment: Post your user,vehicle model where you define your relationships. Have you done that? And have you got a `$vehicle` ? With either model-injection or `$vehicle = Vehicle::findOrFail(1);`

Comment: since the files are big, i have added the relationship part of vehicle and user from both Model files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return your relationships

```
public function user()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function vehicles()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class);
}
```

Comment: It's a mistake easily made, i made it myself :)